# limit the value entered by user in amount field in react

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, regex, validation

i want to restrict the user so that he cannot enter more than 50000 in the input value. how should i achieve this in react?
i am doing this on onchange event.

```
 onPaymentAmountChanged = (e) => {

        let inputValue = e.target.value;
        if ( inputValue > Number(50000)) {
            console.log(inputValue);
            inputValue=inputValue.replace(/[^0-9.]/,"");
        }
}
```

but the above thing is not letting me restrict this. please suggest something

Comment: Just make use of `<input type="number" min="1" max="50000">`. Trying to correct a user's input is rife with problems and produces a terrible user experience. Your goal should be to provide an actionable error message.

Comment: onblur the value changes to 50000.00 will this have any effect? i mean will this work on 50000.00 as well

Comment: Why does it change to `50000.00`? That doesn't sound like standard browser behavior. Anyways, whether or not the decimal points matter is up to you. The important thing is to stop trying to fix the user's input because you'll only make things frustrating.

Answer (score 2):

```
onPaymentAmountChanged = (e) => {
  const inputNumber = parseInt(e.target.value); //parseFloat if you have decimals
  if (Number.isNaN(inputNumber)) {
    console.log(0) // set default state for NAN inputs
  } else if (inputNumber > 50000) {
    console.log(50000) // set state = max value for larger inputs 
  } else {
    console.log(inputNumber)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use react state for change input value

example :

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';

export default function MaxInputValue() {

    const [value, setValue] = useState(10); // default value 10 you can change this

    function handleChange(e) {
        if (Number(e.target.value) > 50000)
            return console.log("more than 50000"); // return if more than 50000

        // else set the input value
        setValue(Number(e.target.value));
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <input value={value} onChange={handleChange}/>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: you need to pass type number to input or validate onChange. you shouldn't set `setValue(50000)`, you should only `return`, because if user wants to type 32456 and types another digit by mistake you are setting value to 5000, and user will have to type all over again.